# Updating google play billing library to version 3 with confusing behavior

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have a functioning Android implementation in-app billing, using the billing client 1.0.2 library and everything works fine. I have a simple premium upgrade, without subscriptions.
Now I tried to upgrade to 3.0.0, I made all the necessary changes to my code (using official documentation, release notes, and StackOverflow) and it seems to work. I know I must recognize all purchases within three days. Failure to correctly recognize purchases will result in reimbursement for these purchases. And that's what I did. Now the point that confuses me:

I tested my purchase workflow another time and debugged all steps to see what happens. Inside handlePurchase in BillingManager, I use the following code, inspired by the official documentation:

```
if (purchase.getPurchaseState() == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
    if (!purchase.isAcknowledged()) {

        AcknowledgePurchaseParams acknowledgePurchaseParams = AcknowledgePurchaseParams.newBuilder().setPurchaseToken(purchase.getPurchaseToken()).build();

        AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener acknowledgePurchaseResponseListener = new AcknowledgePurchaseResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAcknowledgePurchaseResponse(BillingResult billingResult) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Purchase acknowledged", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        };

        mBillingClient.acknowledgePurchase(acknowledgePurchaseParams, acknowledgePurchaseResponseListener);
     }
}
```

In the second line „isAcknowledged()“ always returns true (so the if statement returns false), although the method „acknowledgePurchase“ was never called and will never be called…. Does anybody have an explanation for this behavior? How can it be already acknowledged? Will this result in reimbursement for these purchases in real in app purchases? I only used a trial account.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Have you called consumeAsync() before this code snippet? For consumables, the consumeAsync() method fulfills the acknowledgement requirement.

Comment: No, I don't call consumeAsynch(), it's a simple premium upgrade, no consumable purchases. Does anybody have the same problem? Maybe it's because of the trial account?

Comment: Based on my understanding and previous experience, purchases made with test accounts also need to be acknowledged, and it should be done in 3 min instead of 3 days. But acknowledgement may also be done on server side. Did you use Play Developer API to acknowledge purchases?

Comment: Thank you for your answer Hanrui. Thats also what I understood and I have absolutely no idea why "isAcknowledged()" always returns true... Maybe because a previous purchase of the same item on the same device has been acknowledged?

Comment: Did you mean you had used another account to login and bought that item before? That should be a possible reason. But if that was the case, you should be able to acknowledge after clearing Play Store (and maybe Play service as well) cache. By the way, purchases are binding to the Google Play account, not 3rd party app account. So if you just log out of your own app and log in with another app account, you should not be able to purchase that same item (with the same Play account).

Comment: Thank you for your help Hanrui. After creating a completely new Google account and testing the purchase workflow, everything works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason for the behavior described in my question:

I used the same Google account for testing the purchase workflow before (although it is a simple premium upgrade without subscriptions there is a simple trick for "consuming" this purchase and rebuy it again for testing) and that led it to return "true" from "isAcknowledged()".

After creating a completely new Google account and testing the complete workflow again, everything works fine and the process of acknowledging a purchase can be observed in debug mode!